# Как сделать так чтобы цикл начинался с начала по определенной функции

Tags: android, kotlin, while

Возник такой вопрос есть цикл while. А есть ли возможность сделать так чтобы я писал ему функцию и только посде него он начинался с начала, т.е

```
while(условие){
  button.setOnClickListener{
      функция которая начинает цикл заново
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = 0
while (i < 10) {
   if (что-то происходит) {
     // функция которая начинает цикл заново:
     i = 0 
     continue
  }
  ...
  i++
}
```

Comment: А можно ли сделать также только через setOnClickListener вместо if или это работает только с if?

Comment: @ДмитрийКолесник Я ничего не понял.

Comment: Я имел в виду можно ли также начинать цикл заново но с использованием  OnClickListener т.е чтобы я нажимал на кнопку и только посде этого цикл переходил бы в начало.